# 2 графика на hightchart на 1 странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно вывести 2 графика на `HightCharts` на 1 странице.

Вывожу получаю 1 график.

```js
var options;
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});

function init() {
  options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],

      labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -3,
        y: 20,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
        }
      }

    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function() {}
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name: '',
      data: []
    }]
  }

  $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
    options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
    options.series[0].name = json['name'];
    options.series[0].data = json['data'];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
}

{
  init();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: renderTo: 'container', а где для container2? Потому и не показывает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы рендерите оба графика в одном контейнере.

```js
$(function() {
  init('container', 'data.php');
  init('container2', 'data2.php');
});
 
function init(container, dataSource) {
  options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: container,
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -3,
        y: 20,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
          click: function() {
          }
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: '',
    data: []
  }]
 }
 
 //$.getJSON(dataSource, function(json) {
   options.xAxis.categories = [];
   options.series[0].name = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'];
   options.series[0].data = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
 //});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 110px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 110px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: А как вывести данные на 2 график?

Comment: //$.getJSON("data.php", function(json){
   options.xAxis.categories = [];
   options.series[0].name = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'];
   options.series[0].data = [Math.random(10), Math.random(10), Math.random(10)];
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
 //});

Comment: @Ильяс Бадыганов, я добавил в функцию `init()` 2-й параметр `dataType`. Его можно добавлять как параметр к вашему AJAX запросу и уже в зависимости от параметра на стороне сервера определять какие данные возвращать.

Comment: Ну у меня 2 разных источника json запроса.
1. например data.php
2. data2.php

На 1 графике вывод с data.php. На 2 график data2.php

Comment: @Ильяс Бадыганов, обновил ответ.

Comment: Выводиться только 1 график.

Comment: @Ильяс Бадыганов, выводится только 1 график тут через `Выполнить код` или у вас?
Если тут, то нужно проскролить окно до 2-го графика. Если у вас, то перепроверьте ваш код и сравните его с кодом из ответа.

Comment: Не выводиться у меня. Тут выводиться. Т.к. он данные берет произвольно.
А у меня нужно вывести через data.php и data2.php.
Но выводится только 1 график.
Ниже код

Comment: Не могу понять, как отрендрить на 2 блок. Помогите))

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  init('container', 'data.php');
  init('container2', 'data2.php');
});
 
function init(container, dataSource) {
  options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: container,
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -3,
        y: 20,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
          click: function() {
          }
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: '',
    data: []
  }]
 }
 
$.getJSON(dataSource, function(json) {
   options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
   options.series[0].name = json['name'];
   options.series[0].data = json['data'];
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 
 
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```